# cross browser positioning compatibility

Tags: css

I have a very precisely positioned set of small elements in a header on a website.  I've run it through caniuse.com and refactored any properties that might be problematic.  It's showing up correctly in current versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. When I look at the mobile simulator in Chrome, it appears to have broken, but on an actual phone, it looks fine.

I'm using Bootstrap, fwiw.

Are there any tools that can tell me if my elements will be positioned correctly across browsers?  How can I better plan for this?  I'm the only dev here, and in over my head.

Comment: Chrome's mobile inspector is great for initial checks, but is never 100% correct -- especially with JS/jquery interactions (because you still use a mouse, it doesn't read touch events). If you're a javascript dev, something like browsersync (via gulp or grunt) always works well for me. It lets you access the site from other devices on your network. Using a taskrunner like gulp to serve the site will also prevent cross-domain issues. Here's a sample gulp setup: https://gist.github.com/feliperoberto/9793674

Comment: Another solution is to use `http-server` via node, or python's `SimpleHTTPServer` via `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, which will also allow you to access the site over the local network

Comment: pixel perfect is only for print, there's too many  medias and possible dedicated browsers  around to check on them all . You have to let it go at one point or look for alternatives.

Comment: Use browserstack.com for testing on actual devices to avoid inaccurate simulations.